# Equivalent of NSDictionary's objectsForKeys for Swift dictionaries

Tags: swift

Is there an equivalent of NSDictionary's `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` for Swift dictionaries ?

Comment: You are talking about [`objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:)?

Comment: That should be relatively easy using the `map()` method on the keys array.

Comment: Yup that method. And yes, map() is a great idea, I haven't though of that !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually Martin R's suggestion using `map()` is a great way to go and it's very swifty !

```
myKeys.map({ myDict[$0] })
```

which will return an array of optionals !

Answer (score -1):

```
extension Dictionary {
  public subscript(k1: Key, k2: Key, ks: Key...) -> [Value?] {
    get { return ([k1, k2] + ks).map { k in self[k] } }
    set { for (k, v) in zip([k1, k2] + ks, newValue) { self[k] = v } }
  }
}

let dict = [1:"a", 2:"b", 4:"d"]

dict[1, 2, 3, 4] // ["a", "b", nil, "d"]
```

Comment: doesn't provide answer to the question "is there an equivalent of..."? Moreover absence of narrative is generally bad form